# ¿Qué lógica uso para que un bucle acepte una condición hasta un determinado momento?

Tags: c#, regex, validación

Necesito hacer una validación de un string con expresiones regulares para que se repita un loop que tiene la condición de que hasta que el usuario ingrese una identificación alfanumérica, no pueda seguir adelante con el ingreso de datos. La expresión regular ya está armada correctamente.

Lo que me falla es la lógica para que este loop se repita hasta que la identificación sea una alfanumérica de 4 dígitos y ahí sí, se podría continuar ingresando datos.

Código:

```
public static void validaralfanum(string unNum)
{
    bool bandera = false;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,]*$");

    do
    {
        if (!regex.IsMatch(unNum))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El ID debe ser alfanumérico");
        }
        else if (unNum.ToString().Length > 4 || unNum.ToString().Length < 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El ID debe ser de 4 digitos");
        }
        else if (unNum == null || unNum == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un ID");
        }
        else
        {
            bandera = true;
        }
    }
    while (!bandera);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que actualizar el valor, `unNum`, o de lo contrario pasará lo siguiente:

> El ID debe ser de 4 dígitos
>   El ID debe ser de 4 dígitos
>   El ID debe ser de 4 dígitos
>   ...

También hay que poner `string.IsNullOrEmpty` en lugar de `s == "" || s == null` y una verificación de longitud en `regex`.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,]{4}$");
do
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(unNum))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un ID");
    }
    else if (!regex.IsMatch(unNum))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El ID debe ser alfanumérico");
    }
    else
    {
        bandera = true;
    }
    unNum = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (!bandera);
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ /usr/bin/mono Test.exe
123
El ID debe ser alfanumérico
*&^(^*
El ID debe ser alfanumérico
abcd
$
```

Comment: Pero en esta modificación que le hiciste a mi código tampoco actualizaste el valor, sigo teniendo el loop infinito.

Comment: `var unNum = Console.ReadLine();` es donde yo actualizo. Hay un ejemplo ahora :)

Comment: el problema es que me da un error, ya que yo ya defino `alpha` como parámetro de mi método y no me deja declararlo de nuevo.

Comment: Está bien, `var unNum = Console.ReadLine();` -> `unNum = Console.ReadLine();` :)

Comment: Modifiqué un detallecito y ahora anda casi perfecto, solo que cuando llega al momento de `unNum = Console.ReadLine();` debo apretar dos veces enter para continuar, pero aparte de ese detalle anda perfecto, si tenes idea como arreglar ese detalle menor genial sino lo damos por terminado.

Comment: `unNum = Console.ReadLine();` es en la parte superior o inferior de `do..while`?

Comment: tu lo pusiste en la parte superior, yo lo cambié a la parte inferior asi cuando debo hacer doble enter es luego de ya haber ingresado el código correctamente, si lo pongo en la parte superior debo hacer doble enter antes de comenzar la validación. Es un detalle nomás, si no se te ocurre como arreglarlo no hay problema, me ayudaste bastante ya.

Comment: Extraño! No estoy seguro, una búsqueda de un otro `Console.ReadLine` podría ser útil - donde esta la llamada a la función?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un ID de 4 dígitos para el Lote (Alfanumérico): ");
            string unNum= Console.ReadLine();
            validaralfanum(unNum);` Vendría a ser esta parte, dentro del Main.

Comment: Podría ser talvez porque estamos haciendo doble Console.ReadLine() ?

Comment: `public static void validaralfanum(string unNum)` -> `public static string validaralfanum()` y `var unNum = Console.ReadLine();` en la parte superior de `do..while` y `return unNum` en la parte inferior de `validaralfanum` podría funcionar.

Utilizar `Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un ID de 4 dígitos para el Lote (Alfanumérico): "); string unIdlote =  validaralfanum();` para la llamada a la función?

Comment: "Podría ser porque estamos haciendo doble Console.ReadLine ()?" - sí! Pensé que.  
Quiero `Console.ReadLine` solo en `validaralfanum`

Comment: no funciona correctamente lo que me pasaste recién porque luego de mostrar el error en el formato, continua de todas formas con el resto de las preguntas.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lol768/8dc865499c13c63b7be7423aec680c1c esta bien para mi

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que `unNum` nunca se modifica dentro de esta función. Se acepta por parámetro, y por lo tanto las condiciones para abandonar el bucle nunca cambian. Deberías hacer el bucle conteniendo la entrada de datos del usuario, de forma que cuando lo ingrese correctamente, salga del bucle.

Resumiendo: Saca el bucle de la función de validación y ponlo en la superior.

Comment: Deberías mostrar cómo queda el código final, luego de hacer esos pasos.